# How to reduce couchdb map function emitting multiple rows

Tags: mapreduce, couchdb

I am attempting to get data from couchdb view:

trying to join various documents to get product data, now I want to reduce the sum of likes

here is my MAP function :

```
function (doc) {
 if(doc.$type==='perks'){
      emit(doc._id, {_id: doc._id,price:doc.price});
 }
  if(doc.$type==='discount'){
    if( doc.perks) {
      doc.perks.forEach(function(perk) {
        emit(perk, {_id: doc._id,discount:doc.discount});
      });
    }
   }
  if(doc.$type==='likes'){
    if( doc.perks) {
      doc.perks.forEach(function(perk) {
          emit(perk, 1);
      });
    }
   }
}
```

I want result in below format

```
{
  perkId : 'perk1',
  price : '100',
  discountId : 'discount1',
  discount : '10'
  likes : 20
}
```

Comment: So what problem are you needing help with?

Comment: how to reduce this map function to get desired result ie. {perkId : 'perk1',
  price : '100',
  discountId : 'discount1',
  discount : '10'
  likes : 20}